# How to take user input in python and generate that input with value some other text in a text file?

Tags: python, file, input, text, output

I want to take user input form the console, after taking the input value i'm calling some cli commands, after that i want to generate a text file regarding the result logs of this process.

Problem is while I'm taking input and generating text file then the input prompt goes inside the text file and while I'm giving the input it is not visible in the console.

```
import os
import json

def createStack():
    try:
        inputVal = input('Please enter stack name');
        cmd_stackCreation = "aws --region us-east-1 cloudformation create-stack --stack-name " + inputVal + " --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --template-body file://vss-storage-tables-cf-template-01.json"
        returned_value_StackCreation = os.system(cmd_stackCreation)
        return returned_value_StackCreation
    except Exception as e:
        # Exception occured
        print(e)
        return "error"
```

How to fix it?

`docker run -it --env-file credentials v2sbase | tee -a stack-output.txt`

Comment: Post your python code. That helps in debugging.

Comment: @Mithilesh_Kunal this is my code
import os

import json

def createStack():
 
try:


  inputVal = input('Please enter stack name');

  cmd_stackCreation =
 "aws --region us-east-1 cloudformation create-stack --stack-name "+inputVal+" --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --template-body file://vss-storage-tables-cf-template-01.json"


  returned_value_StackCreation = os.system(cmd_stackCreation)


  return returned_value_StackCreation


 except Exception as e:


  # Exception occured


  print(e)


  return "error"
```python index.py | tee -a output.txt```

Comment: Please add the code in your question as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)